# How to set the image button in the nested activity?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have a page with 6 image buttons when the user clicks on each of them will go to the detail page which contains the image of that icon with extra information. The question is how can I set the image in the detail page corresponds to the image button which the user clicked? for example when user clicked on image button 1 in the detail page see the image button1 when clicked on image button 2 in the detail page we have image of button2, how can I define this property in the activity page code?

here is my code corresponding to 6 image buttons:

//implement the OnClickListener interface
public class Destination extends ActionBarActivity
        implements View.OnClickListener

{

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.destination);


    //get the Button reference
    //Button is a subclass of View
    //buttonClick if from main.xml "@+id/buttonClick"
    View btnClick = findViewById(R.id.image1);
    View btnClick2 = findViewById(R.id.image2);
    View btnClick3 = findViewById(R.id.image3);
    View btnClick4 = findViewById(R.id.image4);
    View btnClick5 = findViewById(R.id.image5);
    View btnClick6 = findViewById(R.id.image6);
    btnClick.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnClick2.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnClick3.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnClick4.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnClick5.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnClick6.setOnClickListener(this);
}

//override the OnClickListener interface method
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if (arg0.getId() == R.id.image1) {
        //define a new Intent for the second Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DestinationTherapy.class);
        //start the second Activity
        this.startActivity(intent);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.image2) {
        //define a new Intent for the second Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DestinationDetail.class);
        //start the second Activity
        this.startActivity(intent);
    } else  if (arg0.getId() == R.id.image3) {
        //define a new Intent for the second Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(Destination.this, DestinationDetail.class);
        //start the second Activity
        this.startActivity(intent);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.image4) {
        //define a new Intent for the second Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(Destination.this, DestinationDetail.class);
        //start the second Activity
        this.startActivity(intent);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.image5) {
        //define a new Intent for the second Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(Destination.this, DestinationDetail.class);
        //start the second Activity
        this.startActivity(intent);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.image6) {
        //define a new Intent for the second Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(Destination.this, DestinationDetail.class);
        //start the second Activity
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detail, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Setting.class));
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.action_menu) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Destination Detail activity:

```
public class DestinationDetail extends ActionBarActivity
    implements View.OnClickListener
```

{

```
    View btnClick = findViewById(R.id.emergency4);
    btnClick.setOnClickListener(DestinationDetail.this);
    View btnClick1 = findViewById(R.id.back2);
    btnClick1.setOnClickListener(DestinationDetail.this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detail, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_menu) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if (arg0.getId() == R.id.emergency4) {
        //define a new Intent for the second Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EmergencyCall.class);
        //start the second Activity
        this.startActivity(intent);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.back2) {
            //define a new Intent for the second Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Destination.class);
            //start the second Activity
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Pass the res id of the image in the `Intent`

In `Destination` activity, in `onClick()` write something like:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();
    // ... 
    if (id == R.id.image1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DestinationTherapy.class);
        intent.putExtra("res_id", R.drawable.image1);    
        startActivity(intent); 
    } else if ( //... 
}
```

Change `R.drawable.image1` to the appropriate res id. In your case it will be different for each image, so you need a kind of if/switch construct.

In `DestinationDetail` get a handle of the image and set it to that

```
setContentView(...); 
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_detail_image_view);
int resId = getIntent().getIntExtra("res_id", 0);
iv.setImageResource(resId);
```

You must change `R.id.my_detail_image_view` with the appropriate view id of your ImageView in `DestinationDetail`

*Clarification (view id vs res id)*: a view id is the one you define like `android:id="@+id/my_view_id"` in xml. A res id for an image is automatically generated for you when you put the image in the drawable folders. You can use it in java with `R.id.image_name_without_extension` or in xml with `@drawable/image_name_without_extension`

Comment: thanks, but I did not understand where should I put the code in the DestinationDetail page?

Comment: The second snippet goes in onCreate() of DestinationDetail. Modify your ids appropriately

Comment: PS: I don't see a call to setContentView() there... you should have it, otherwise your view hierarchy won't be bound to the Window and you won't see anything

Comment: but i don't have it in my code , can you please change my code and add it in the proper place for me , I appreciate in advance.

Comment: I could but I don't know the layout for your DestinationDetail activity. It is something like R.layout.your_layout. Without that it should crash when you start the DestinationDetail activity

Comment: Thanks a loooooooooooot, you saved a lot of time for me , I appreciate.

Comment: No problem. If the answer helped you, consider accepting it. (I think you did and then you removed it)